# Firefox encodes URI for pushState -- workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, pushstate, html5-history

In Firefox, when you use `window.history.pushState`, it automatically encodes the URI for you. In other browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari), it does not. So, if you want your URI encoded, you need to do it yourself (i.e. with `encodeURI`) -- unless you're using Firefox.

To see this for yourself, run this code in the Chrome dev console and the Firefox dev console:

```
window.history.pushState({},'asdf','#spaces or percent twenties');
location.href;
// Firefox: "...#spaces%20or%020percent%20twenties"
// Other browsers: "...#spaces or percent twenties"
```

[The W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) for `window.history.pushState` doesn't specify to encode the URI, so I think this is an error on Firefox's part.

In the meantime before this is unified, though, I need a workaround to make Firefox play nice. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's interesting - I'm finding that the opposite behavior is true - FF fails to encode the spaces, other browsers do. FF version 58.0.2.

Comment: @skwidbreth I just tested the code in my question on Windows, and got the outputs my question predicts: on FF v58.0.2 I get `...#spaces%20or%20percent%20twenties` and on IE11 I get `...#spaces or percent twenties`.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm on Mac - I wonder if that makes a difference?

Comment: I was on a mac when I posted this question originally. Are you looking at what is displayed in the URL bar, or what is printed when you put `location.href` in the console? Because FF displays `%20` in the URL bar as a space character.